# Idiom for "Single out" in a negative way

Tags: idioms, synonyms

In a small group of people, the leader singled out Person A to pick on her. What's another idiom (that's a verb) to describe this action? There was a two-word idiom which I cannot remember. The idiom is used as thus: "The leader ___'d person A ____.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example makes me think of the phrasal verb, "Call out".

call out

vb (adverb)
1. to utter aloud, esp loudly

2. (tr) to summon
3. (Industrial Relations & HR Terms) (tr) to order (workers) to strike
4. (Industrial Relations & HR Terms) (tr) to summon (an employee) to work at a time outside his normal working hours, usually in an emergency
5. (tr) to challenge to a duel

Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Comment: Yes! This was the one I was after.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than a few (mostly of a vernacular nature):

1. [*To chew out*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chew+out)

   > To scold or reprimand someone
2. [*To tear a person a new a___hole*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tear+someone+a+new+asshole)

   > to chastise someone severely

The idioms by themselves do not convey the public nature of the singling out. I personally prefer to use *public execution*, after the practice of executing criminals in full view of public. I don't think that's a standard use of the phrase, but I use it in that sense

Comment: Thanks! Both are great suggestions. The second one sounds to me like a somewhat harsh one.